# Redirect specific IP using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip-address

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to do a 301 redirect for a particular IP address (in this case brute force password bot).  I want to send this guy to a project honeypot link rather than just banning the IP.  Something like the following?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
Redirect 301 ^/adminlogin/$ http://www.example.com/honeypotlink.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RewriteCond` has to be followed by a `RewriteRule`. And your `RewriteCond` has an `!` which is a negation. It should look more like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule ^/adminlogin/$ http://www.example.com/honeypotlink.php [R=301,L]
```